# How to set google-maps-for-rails infowindow render true/false from the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/) in a Rails app.

In the Model controller I have

```
def gmap_settings(location, marker)
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/path/to/partial", :locals => { :object => location})
end
```

I'm displaying maps in several views. In some cases, displaying multiple maps in the same page.

Some maps need an infowindow, but others do not.

How can I define whether the infowindow is rendered or not from the view?

Comment: You share the same json between different maps?

Comment: yes! sorry I lost track. Your comment got me thinking along the right lines. I did need the same json on different maps, so I just created two 'gmap_settings' methods in the controller. One with infowindows, one without. Easy, when you think the right way :). I was looking at passing locals in the view, which obviously is not correct. Your comment got me in the right direction, maybe you'd like to post an answer.

Comment: Ok, good news! Upvoted a nice answer of yours previously concerning the gem, this reminded me of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the json, the `description` triggers the infowindow creation.

Simply remove or adapt what you pass to the `gmaps` helper.